# Sorting record array twice while maintaining initial sort

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

so I have the following query for my companies
`companies.where(industry: industries_queried)`

I would like to sort them, so that the first records returned are the ones with plan_id == 3, then 2, then 1. (descendingly)

But then, I would also like to arrange each of these 4 parts, so that they are sorted alphabetically per name.

How would I go about doing this in Rails 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Active [Record Query Interface guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering), gives us the following info on ordering records.

> #### [4 Ordering](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering)
>
> To retrieve records from the database in a specific order, you can use
> the [`order`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.1/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-order) method.
>
> For example, if you're getting a set of records and want to order them
> in ascending order by the `created_at` field in your table:
>
> ```
> Customer.order(:created_at)
> # OR
> Customer.order("created_at")
> ```
>
> You could specify `ASC` or `DESC` as well:
>
> ```
> Customer.order(created_at: :desc)
> # OR
> Customer.order(created_at: :asc)
> # OR
> Customer.order("created_at DESC")
> # OR
> Customer.order("created_at ASC")
> ```
>
> Or ordering by multiple fields:
>
> ```
> Customer.order(orders_count: :asc, created_at: :desc)
> # OR
> Customer.order(:orders_count, created_at: :desc)
> # OR
> Customer.order("orders_count ASC, created_at DESC")
> # OR
> Customer.order("orders_count ASC", "created_at DESC")
> ```

Applying this to your issue you would end up with:

```
companies.where(industry: industries_queried).order(plan_id: :desc, name: :asc)
```